# Can I run Batch code so each Iteration of the Batch has its own Execution Context for an API call?

Tags: apex, batch

I have have a list of formats of a file I need to download via API from a 3rd party service.

```
List<String> FileFormatList = new List<String>{a1s,
                                               a1s3,
                                               absent,
                                               accountantsworld,
                                               ...};
// FileFormatList.size() = 178
```

I want to do something like:

```
ThirdPartyConnection ApiCon = new ThirdPartyConnection('credentials');
Id ParentId;
for(String FileFormat :FileFormatList){
    try{
        String FileCsvString = ApiCon.getFile(FileFormat);
        Attachment FileAttachment = new Attachment(Name=FileFormat+'.csv',
                                                   Body=Blob.valueOf(FileCsvString),
                                                   ParentId=ParentId);
        insert FileAttachment;
    } catch(Exception Whoops){
        System.debug('ERROR @ '+FileFormat+'; Exception: '+Whoops);
    }
}
```

The issue is that each instance of the `for` loop really needs its own Execution Context.  *Can this be done with **Batch code** / `implementing Database.batachable`?*

---

PS:  I am writing this Q&A-style and will be posting an example

Answer (score 1):

I think [this post](http://andyinthecloud.com/2013/08/11/batch-worker-getting-more-done-with-less-work/) will get you there - it explains how you can invoke a batch with a scope of 1 with a iterator (in your case a List) - so using this approach, you can pass each string from the list into its own batch execution